# Moodle with Java Or any other LMS that fits this requirement

Tags: java

My requirement is to access moodle as a backend engine and front end will be mint in Java[jsf]
now I want to know that is there any interface available to access Moodle from Java , using WebServices or any APIs or anything.

Initially I tried using Sakai which is in Java, but the problem is there is no clear API written for it.

So let me know the option for using Moodle from JAVA.

Also if it is possible than what will be the feature available through the WebServices or API. ?

Or any other LMS that is in Java and provide API or WebService to make this working.

Comment: Or any other alternative LMS that webservice interface or clear API to access their system

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed many [LMS](http://barrysampson.com/2009/04/open-source-lms-10-alternatives-to-moodle/) (dokeos, docebo, ATutor) last year and to be frank all of them sucked. Moodle was the most stable, had more plugins and a huge community.

I came across [Project Sakai](http://sakaiproject.org/features), I havn't tried it, but sounds promising. Something very interesting from Google is [cloudcourse](http://code.google.com/p/cloudcourse/) (in python I guess, but looks awesome [demo](https://cloudcourseio.appspot.com/)). But not a complete LMS (compared to moodle).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add [Chamilo](http://www.chamilo.org) they have a list of available web services (SOAP) that you can use to create courses, users, add users to courses, etc

Answer (score 0):

https://www.olat.org/ and https://www.openolat.com seem a good alternative to moodle.